# Git merge two homogeneous repositories

Tags: git, merge

I have two repositories that are diffs of one single codebase. 
One is a `staging` repository and the other is `dev`.

I've looked online for solutions to this, but the answers I'm receiving are based on merging disparate parts of a single app either as a submodule or other.

I did try and create two branches on a new repository, and copy the code across and commit respectively. However when I attempt to merge the two branches it just informs me that everything is already up to date.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: sounds like the repositories are the same and there is nothing to merge. Do the SHAs of the commits at the branches you try to merge differ?

Comment: Yes they differ, there are additions made to the staging code base.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are merging `dev/branch1` into `staging/branch2`, you could do:

a) `git log dev/branch1 --not staging/branch2` to check what will go from branch1. From what you say this should be empty.

b) `git log --not dev/branch1 staging/branch2` should show you the additions of the staging.

When you do

```
git checkout dev/branch1
git merge staging/branch2
```

your should be fast-forwarded to `staging/branch2` in case there were no extra commits in `dev/branch1` (step a). At this point you may push your `HEAD` to development: `git push dev HEAD:branch1`

NB: I wouldn't use local branches to avoid confusion.

Technically when a) gives you empty output, you may avoid merge step alltogether:

```
git push dev staging/branch1:branch2
```

in case you missed something the push will be rejected, as long as you do not force it with the `-f` flag.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm trying to use cherry-picks instead now.